# Postgres Conditional Select?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, join

I'm not really sure how to describe this problem without an example, so here's an example:

I have three tables:

Table 1: Boxes

```
BoxID | Box Name | Box Cost
1 | Bob's Box | $20
2 | Matt's Box | $21
3 | Jacob's Box | $22
4 | Beth's Box | $23
5 | Rachel's Box | $24
```

Table 2: Box_ProcessIDs

```
BoxID | ParentProcessID
1 | 123
2 | 456
3 | 789
4 | 012
5 | 234
```

Table 3: Box_Processes

```
ParentProcess | ChildProcess | Start Time | End Time | ProcessName 
123 | AAA | 1:00 | 1:05 | Invoiced
123 | AAB | 1:30 | 1:35 | Packed
123 | BBB | 2:00 | 2:05 | Shipped

456 | CDD | 3:15 | 3:20 | Invoiced
456 | DDD | 3:25 | 3:30 | Packaging_Complete
456 | CCD | 3:35 | 3:40 | Shipped

789 | EEE | 4:15 | 4:20 | Invoiced
789 | EEF | 4:25 | 4:30 | Done_Packing
789 | EFF | 4:35 | 4:40 | Shipped
```

I want the output columns to be:
Box Name, Box Cost, Box Shipping Duration, Box Packing Duration, Box Invoice Duration

I know I can use like %pack% to select my packing fields, and I can figure out how to use Date_Part or somesuch to get my durations, but I'm at a loss as to how to get my `shipping duration`, `packing duration`, and `invoice duration` into separate fields.

Comment: As *always*, please provide the version number of PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to do something like this pseudo-sql?

```
select b.box_name, b.box_cost,
bp2.end_time - bp2.start_time as box_shipping_duration,
bp3.end_time - bp3.start_time as box_packing_duration,
bp1.end_time - bp1.start_time as box_invoice_duration
from boxes b

join box_processids bpid on b.boxid = bpid.boxid

left outer join box_processes bp1 on bpid.parentprocessid = bp1.parentprocess
and processname = 'Invoiced'

left outer join box_processes bp2 on bpid.parentprocessid = bp2.parentprocess
and processname = 'Shipped'

left outer join box_processes bp3 on bpid.parentprocessid = bp3.parentprocess
and processname = 'Packed'
```

(will need null checks, proper datetime handling, better names and so on)

Comment: Thank you -- this is exactly what I was looking for! Is there a name for this kind of problem / method / solution?

Answer (score 2):

First off, your design is flawed. `time` is no good for this purpose. It breaks as soon as you cross midnight. Use [`timestamp` or `timestamptz`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) instead.

Next, since unquoted identifiers are cast to lower case automatically in PostgreSQL, your naming convention is no good either. I adapted it to something more useful.

```
CREATE TABLE boxes (box_id int PRIMARY KEY, box_name text, box_cost numeric);
INSERT INTO boxes VALUES
  (1, 'Bob''s Box', 20)
 ,(2, 'Matt''s Box', 21)
 ,(3, 'Jacob''s Box', 22)
 ,(4, 'Beth''s Box', 23)
 ,(5, 'Rachel''s Box', 24);

CREATE TABLE box_processids (
  box_id int 
 ,parentprocess_id int
 ,PRIMARY KEY(box_id, parentprocess_id)
);

INSERT INTO box_processids  VALUES
  (1, 123)
 ,(2, 456)
 ,(3, 789)
 ,(4, 012)
 ,(5, 234);

CREATE TABLE box_processes (
  parentprocess_id int
 ,childprocess_id char(3)
 ,start_time timestamp
 ,end_time timestamp
 ,processname text
 ,PRIMARY KEY(parentprocess_id, childprocess_id)
);

INSERT INTO box_processes VALUES
  (123, 'AAA', '2013-2-10 1:00', '2013-2-10 1:05', 'Invoiced')
 ,(123, 'AAB', '2013-2-10 1:30', '2013-2-10 1:35', 'Packed')
 ,(123, 'BBB', '2013-2-10 2:00', '2013-2-10 2:05', 'Shipped')

 ,(456, 'CDD', '2013-2-10 3:15', '2013-2-10 3:20', 'Invoiced')
 ,(456, 'DDD', '2013-2-10 3:25', '2013-2-10 3:30', 'Packaging_Complete')
 ,(456, 'CCD', '2013-2-10 3:35', '2013-2-10 3:40', 'Shipped')

 ,(789, 'EEE', '2013-2-10 4:15', '2013-2-10 4:20', 'Invoiced')
 ,(789, 'EEF', '2013-2-10 4:25', '2013-2-10 4:30', 'Done_Packing')
 ,(789, 'EFF', '2013-2-10 4:35', '2013-2-10 4:40', 'Shipped');
```

Your query could then look like this:

```
SELECT b.box_name
      ,b.box_cost
      ,(i.end_time - i.start_time) AS box_invoice_duration
      ,(p.end_time - p.start_time) AS box_packing_duration
      ,(s.end_time - s.start_time) AS box_shipping_duration
FROM   boxes               b
LEFT   JOIN box_processids bp USING (box_id)
LEFT   JOIN box_processes  i ON i.parentprocess_id = bp.parentprocess_id
                            AND i.processname = 'Invoiced'
LEFT   JOIN box_processes  p ON i.parentprocess_id = bp.parentprocess_id
                            AND p.processname = 'Packed'
LEFT   JOIN box_processes  s ON i.parentprocess_id = bp.parentprocess_id
                            AND s.processname = 'Shipped'
```

[**->sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/41082/1)
Use [`to_char()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html) to format your `interval` any way you want.

Comment: `timestamp` breaks whenever the clock moves backwards at the end of Daylight Saving Time, so I strongly recommend `timestamptz` instead. Basically, it's the right type to use when you want to capture a point in time rather than something like a local (single-timezone) appointment time. If the government changes DST rules before the appointment date arrives, you want the appointment to stay the same in local time but move to a new sidereal time, which is the behavior of timestamp.